# How to iterate through multiple header in excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to access these rows that have header as a date and in date there are some other columns which are repeating for each date. can anyone know how can i iterate over and access them.

I have dates in header 1,2,3,4 and in header 1 some columns are there which is also a heading. as i have show you how my excel sheet look like. 
I want to iterate thorugh each row and do some stuff. as some columns are in header 1 that columns are same in 2,3,4,... no change in the field names.

````
data_f = pandas.read_excel(input_excel_file_path,  header=[0, 1], sheet_name = 'Attend_Attendance')
    print(list(data_f.columns.values))

________________________________________________________________________________________________________
____|_____|        Header1    |        Header2     |        Header3      |        Header4     |        Header5      |
ColX|ColY |ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD||ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|
1   | ds  | 5  | 6  |9   |10  | ..................................................................................
2   | dh  |  ...................................................................................
3   | ge  |  ....................................................................................
4   | ew  |  ...................................................................................
5   | er  |  ......................................................................................```
````

Comment: search for multiindex in pandas. I think that will solve your problems.

Comment: Yeah i search it  ```filtered_data = data_f.loc[:, (slice(None), ('In Time','Out Time','Total Hours','Assigned Shift','Status', 'Shortage of Hrs','Deviation From Shift'))]
    print(filtered_data)``` I use this to see the data but like in colX and colY i have employee name and id so i have to iterate through each row. and in header 1,2,3 .... there are different dates.